# Clearing part of the Rails cache and not all of it with Rails.cache.clear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to clear part of my rails cache. My problem is that there are logs that are being cached that need to be cleared but if I clear the whole cache active users will be logged out of the site.

Comment: It sounds very wrong. Can you elaborate? How is login status dependent on the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm using a cache based session store, when the cache gets cleared the user gets logged out of their session.

I did some research and unfortunately...

> If you ever need to reset your cache (say you upgraded Rails and your
>   old cached data is no longer accurate), there’s no way to do that
>   without expiring everyone’s sessions.

-- via [Justin Weiss's blog](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/)

If we ever want to remedy the issue of clearing sessions when the cache is cleared we will need to store our sessions in the database instead.